# Intel VT-x is enabled in BIOS, but is not recognized by the OS

Tags: x86, virtualization

I want to use an Android emulator like Nox or Bluestacks to play the mobile PUBG on PC. I am aware that enable virtualization in BIOS makes performance much, much better. I have an HP Omen desktop (RX580 4gb, 7th gen i5, 12gb DDR4, 128GB SSD+1TB HDD). The BIOS looks like this:

[image: this].

I went into the Security tab and enabled vt-x, saved, and restarted. However, vt-x isn't being recognized by anything. I have Windows 10 Home, so there is no Hyper-V to disable, nor do I have any antivirus software installed (other than Windows Defender). Do you have any tips as to what I can do so virtualization works? Thanks!

also, can anyone recommend an Android emulator without sponsored apps showing up? One where you just load the .apk and can map controls? Thanks again!

Comment: This doesn’t seem like a programming question. Probably a different forum would be more suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved the same issue:

to make VT-X work you have to check the following things

1. enable virtualization in BIOS (done)
2. disable Hyper-V via "windows features" (done)
3. disable "DeviceGuard" (you can check whether it is enabled via systeminformation). Use `gpedit.msc`to set `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Device Guard` to `Disabled`.

here you can read about DeviceGuard relatiion to VT-X
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=86399

Additionally I did `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just need to run this(Requires administrator privileges):

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```

Reference: 
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8004c3bd-7d57-40ce-93de-0b1a6babd64c/how-i-can-disable-credential-guard?forum=win10itprovirt#8ee5ce15-1fd7-4050-b5e9-c388b806704d